# Google Colab ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pandas-ta

I have the following colab notebook that has always worked for me, however now I am receiving the following error:
"ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"

How can I fix this problem? I have already tried re-installing pands to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
pip install pandas_ta

!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
!pip install Ta-lib

from google.colab import files
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta


def TAfunction(data):
  stock_df = pd.read_csv(data)
  CustomStrategy = ta.Strategy(
    name="RSI Strat",
    description = "RSI",
    ta=[
        {"kind":"rsi"},
        {"kind":"bbands", "length": 5},
        {"kind":"macd", "fast": 8, "slow":21},
        {"kind":"sma", "length": 20},
        {"kind":"sma", "length": 50},]
)
  stock_df.ta.strategy(CustomStrategy)
  stock_df.to_csv(data, encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index=False)

test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Stocks CSVs/IndCSVs/'

for file in os.listdir(test_dir):
  if file.endswith(".csv"):
    TAfunction(test_dir + file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this exact same error while running a `so-vits-svc 4.0` model in Colab. All I had to do was:

1. Click on "Runtime" in the top menu
2. Click on "Restart runtime"
3. Run the cell again